# Late 80s sci-fi show or mini series where humanoid aliens (with a hand protruding from their chest) live among us

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I vaguely remember watching this sci-fi show (which could also have been a mini series) where aliens were among us on Earth. It looked like it was from the late 80s. The aliens looked like people except they had a 3-fingered hand that would come out of their chest. Does anybody have an inkling of what show I'm talking about? I can't find an answer anywhere!

Comment: War of the Worlds? Warning - Jump scare NSFW - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuDc8V2r53g

Answer (score 4):

Is it Fox's *War of the Worlds*?  From Wikipedia:
Along with other sci-fi/horror series that ran in syndication in the late 1980s (such as Friday the 13th: The Series and Freddy's Nightmares), War of the Worlds constantly pushed the “acceptable content” envelope, regularly featuring violence on par with the R-rated horror movies of the time. Gore is commonplace in the first season: dead aliens and their tossed-away hosts’ bodies melt in a grotesque puddle and the ruthless Mor-Taxans have no compunctions about torturing or mutilating any human who gets in their way. One of their trademark methods of murder would be gouged-out eyes courtesy of the third arm that would often burst out from their chest.